# Running Kafka Schema Registry in .Net TestContainer

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I'm trying to get Kafka + Schema Registry to run in TestContainers to call it from an integration test.

```
var _kafkaNetwork = new NetworkBuilder().WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D")).Build();
_kafkaNetwork.CreateAsync().Wait();

var kafkaContainer = new KafkaBuilder().WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.12")
    .WithCleanUp(true)
    .WithNetwork(_kafkaNetwork)
    .WithNetworkAliases("kafka")
    .WithImagePullPolicy(x => x == null)
    .Build();
kafkaContainer.StartAsync().Wait();

var schemaRegistryContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
    .WithExposedPort("8081")
    .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.12")
    .WithCleanUp(true)
    .WithImagePullPolicy(x => x == null)
    .WithNetwork(_kafkaNetwork)
    .WithWaitStrategy(
        Wait.ForUnixContainer()
            .UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(req => req.ForPath("/subjects").ForStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK)))
    .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schemaregistry")
    .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081")
    .WithEnvironment(
        "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS",
        kafkaContainer.GetBootstrapAddress().TrimEnd('/'))
    .Build();

schemaRegistryContainer.StartAsync().Wait();
```

I am getting the following error when the Schema Registry starts up.

```
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ... 
===> Check if Kafka is healthy ...
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-simple-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig - AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [plaintext://127.0.0.1:59024]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 6.2.12-ccs
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 9764f696d804dd0c
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1696958540102
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1696958570130, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1696958570231) timed out at 1696958570131 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Error while getting broker list.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1696958580138, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1696958580239) timed out at 1696958580139 after 1 attempt(s)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:147)
    at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:149)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1696958580138, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1696958580239) timed out at 1696958580139 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:59024) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[main] INFO io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Trying to query Kafka for metadata again ...
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Expected 1 brokers but found only 0. Brokers found [].
Using log4j config /etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties
```

I can use the bootstrap address to connect with Conduktor no problem. I have tried to change the SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS to everything I can think of or going off other similiar questions and still the same error.

Comment: You need to register an extra listener in kafka in order to be able to listen through the docker network and then use it in SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS.

Comment: When you use the function to get the bootstrap, that's for your .NET code to connect, not for containers in the same network. That's what the network aliases are for. In other words, 127.0.0.1 is trying to make the registry container connect to itself not `kafka:9092`, which you can just hard-code. You can also use latest 7.x image, if you wanted

Comment: doing a `.WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", $"PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort}")` is giving the same error that the registry is not able to connect to 127.0.0.1:<random-port>

Comment: the problem is this line: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet/blob/e3be24f8256c21be4525e8abae623695c8bb7fb2/src/Testcontainers.Kafka/KafkaBuilder.cs#L82 , the registry will end up trying to connect to the 127.0.0.1 and mapped port; i rewrote the startup script to return the kafka:9092 instead

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, it helped me to resolve the issue. I now create my kafka container with this code

```cs
var container = new KafkaBuilder()
  .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.2")
  .WithNetworkAliases("kafka")
  .WithNetwork(network)
  .WithStartupCallback((container, ct) =>
  {
      const char lf = '\n';
      var startupScript = new StringBuilder();
      startupScript.Append("#!/bin/bash");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append($"echo 'clientPort={KafkaBuilder.ZookeeperPort}' > zookeeper.properties");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append("echo 'dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data' >> zookeeper.properties");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append("echo 'dataLogDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/log' >> zookeeper.properties");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append("zookeeper-server-start zookeeper.properties &");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append(
          $"export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort},BROKER://{container.IpAddress}:{KafkaBuilder.BrokerPort}");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append("echo '' > /etc/confluent/docker/ensure");
      startupScript.Append(lf);
      startupScript.Append("/etc/confluent/docker/run");
      return container.CopyAsync(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(startupScript.ToString()), KafkaBuilder.StartupScriptFilePath, Unix.FileMode755, ct);
  })
  .Build();
```

and the registry container with

```cs
var container = new ContainerBuilder()
  .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.2")
  .WithNetwork(network)
  .WithExposedPort(8081)
  .WithPortBinding(8081, true)
  .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry")
  .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081")
  .WithEnvironment("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", $"PLAINTEXT://kafka:{KafkaBuilder.KafkaPort}")
  .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilMessageIsLogged("Server started, listening for requests..."))
  .Build();
```